# Unsure about determining an argument's validity

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, predicate-logic, quantifiers

> Suppose that the discourse domain is $\{2,3,\ldots\}$ and
>
> $p(x,y)$: $x$ is a  factor of $y$
>
> $q(x,y,z)$: $z = GCF(x,y)$
>
> $r(x)$: $x$ is prime.
>
> Check whether this argument is valid:
>
> $$ \forall x\exists y\;(p(x,y) \implies r(x))\\ \forall x\forall
> y\forall z\;(\neg q(x,y,z))\\\exists x\forall y\;(p(x,y)  \vee
> r(x)) $$
>
> $$\therefore\quad\forall y\exists z\exists x\;q(x,y,z).$$

I can't decide on my answer because:

- the first and second premises can be disproved and so they're false, and a valid argument can't have false premises
- the second premise and the conclusion contradict each other.

Comment: @Yenus is the following "argument" "valid"? $$0\ne0$$$$\therefore0=0$$

Comment: The argument you gave is invalid but my point is the second premise says that for all x,y and z we can't find any number that satisfies q(x,y,z) but the conclusion says that for some z and x and for all y we can find a number that satisfies q(x,y,z). If one of them is true then the other can't be true. Other question I can see from this is if we're given false premises and we know the conclusion that these premises imply is also false then can the argument be considered valid?

Comment: @Yenus Anne’s presented argument is valid in FOL and invalid in PL. On the other hand, the one I gave below is valid in both PL and FOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Every argument with [inconsistent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4278039/21813) premises** corresponds to a conditional with an [unsatisfiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4512153/21813) antecedent, that is, a conditional that is true *regardless of interpretation*, so **is automatically valid**. For example, this argument is valid: $$1=1\,\text{ and }\,1\ne1; \text{therefore }1=1.$$

> - a valid argument can't have false premises
> - the second premise and the conclusion contradict each other.

The second premise of the above valid argument is false and contradicts its conclusion.

(A false premise makes an argument [unsound](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4232127/21813), but doesn’t invalidate it.)

> > Suppose that the discourse domain is $\{2,3,\ldots\}$ and
> >
> > $P(x,y)$: $x$ is a factor of $y,$
> >
> > $Q(x,y,z)$: $z = GCF(x,y),$
> >
> > $R(x)$: $x$ is prime.

In my first sentence, “*regardless of interpretation*” refers to the fact that an argument's validity depends on its *logical form*. So, the above chunk of information (called an interpretation) is just a red herring.

> > Check whether this argument is valid: $$ \forall x\exists y\;(P(x,y) \implies R(x))\\ \forall x\forall y\forall z\;(\neg Q(x,y,z))\\\exists x\forall y\;(P(x,y)  \vee R(x))\\\therefore\quad\forall y\exists z\exists x\;Q(x,y,z).$$

This argument is invalid, but the red-herring interpretation above gives it a false premise so doesn't reveal this. On the other hand, the following counter-interpretation gives the argument no false premise and a false conclusion:

\begin{align}&\text{discourse domain}=\mathbb R\\P(x,y)\quad&{:\Leftrightarrow}\quad x+y=x+y\\
Q(x,y,z)\quad&{:\Leftrightarrow}\quad x+y+z\ne x+y+z\\
R(x)\quad&{:\Leftrightarrow}\quad x=x.\end{align}

> - the second premise and the conclusion contradict each other.

Incorrect: in the following interpretation, the second premise and conclusion are both false:
\begin{align}\text{discourse domain}=\mathbb Z\\Q(x,y,z)\quad{:\Leftrightarrow}\quad x=y=z=0.\end{align}

---

**Reply to comment**

> > You can validly reach false conclusions from every false premise, for instance, $2=4$ therefore $2+2=4+2$ therefore $4/2=6/2$ therefore $2=3.$
>
> @David So is the argument you gave in your explanation valid? If so, it means that arguments with false premises which reach false conclusions are valid arguments, right?

Not necessarily: this argument, in real analysis, has false premises and conclusion, and is invalid, because in complex analysis its premise is true and its conclusion false: $$\exists x\,x^2{<}0; \text{therefore }1\ne1.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. So in order to determine the invalidity of the argument you looked for values that make the premises true and the conclusion false.But why did you use the set of real numbers as your domain of discourse and can you clarify the interpretation you used to prove the invalidity? I'm having a hard time understanding it and additionally, do you know of any sites or books that explain this further?

Comment: 1. @Yenus What exactly is it about the coutermodel that you need explaining? I'm happy to elaborate. (It still works if you change the discourse domain to $\mathbb C$ or $\{2,3,…\}.$ `:⇔` means 'denotes'.) $\quad$ 2. I've expanded the answer and added some links, hopefully helpful.